# only one notification is set i want to individual notification is display my code is

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

i want to individual notification display and user click on notification to move that notification information is display in result activity screen
  and also not set large icon in notification

i work on reminder application so any suggestion so tell me

```
public void loopReminder() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        remindarNotification();
    }
}

public void remindarNotification() {
    Notification notification;
    AtomicInteger c = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int id = c.incrementAndGet();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Activity_Detail_Screen.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);


    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Activity_Detail_Screen.class);



    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,       
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_reminder);

    String message = "Hello Notification with imagecccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";

    String title = "Notification !!!";
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_notification;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();


    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
            .setWhen(when)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))

            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
            .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    Log.e("AutoIncriment", "Notification Id = > " + id);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Id =" + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
```

Comment: All of your `notify()` calls have the same ID because you're creating a new `AtomicInteger` each time `remindarNotification()` is called.

Comment: i also used   final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 3000;                                                                                                                         NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());                                                            it is not working    Still the same problem with only one notifications displaying if times are same.

Comment: They each need a different ID. Using an ID that's already been used just updates the last `Notification` that has that ID.

Comment: ya its done and how to set all notification group like whatsApp .  i work on reminder application so any suggestion give me how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void fetchReminder() {

    String strCurrentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    String strCurrentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    Log.e("In fetchReminder", "Where Pass Date => " + strCurrentDate + " Time =>  " + strCurrentTime);

    String sel_user = "select * from Tb_Reminder where rem_date<='" + strCurrentDate + "' And rem_time<='" + strCurrentTime + "'";



    Cursor c_user = dbhelper.selectQuery(sel_user);
    Log.e("sel", "" + c_user.getCount());


    if (c_user != null && c_user.getCount() > 0) {

        if (c_user.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                if (c_user.getCount() > 0) {


                    int rem_id = Integer.parseInt(c_user.getString(c_user.getColumnIndex("rem_id")));
                    String rem_gen_datetime = c_user.getString(c_user.getColumnIndex("rem_gen_datetime"));
                    String rem_desc = c_user.getString(c_user.getColumnIndex("rem_desc"));
                    String rem_date = c_user.getString(c_user.getColumnIndex("rem_date"));
                    String rem_time = c_user.getString(c_user.getColumnIndex("rem_time"));

                    Log.e("Fetch Value rem_id = ", +rem_id + "  rem_gen_datetime =" + rem_gen_datetime + "  rem_desc= " + rem_desc + "  rem_date= " + rem_date + "  rem_time= " + rem_time);
                    String ReminderDateTime = rem_date + "  " + rem_time;
                    addNotification(rem_id,rem_desc, ReminderDateTime);

                }

            } while (c_user.moveToNext());
        }
    } else {
        c_user.close();
        Log.e("Empty", "No Reminder is Available");
    }
    if (c_user != null) {
        c_user.close();
    }

}
```

// notification mentod

private void addNotification(int rem_id,String desc, String reminderdatetime) {

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Activity_Detail_Screen.class);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int namMessage = 0;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                    .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                    .setContentText(desc + " On:" + reminderdatetime)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_reminder, "Snooze", contentIntent)

                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);



    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(rem_id, builder.build());
}
```